# Getting custom user attributes in a service, they return NULL

Tags: plugin-development

I'm building a service where a few user attributes (category fields) are needed and have to be compared against an entry.

However, when I get the current user and try to load these attributes, they show as `NULL`. They are filled in at the user's profile, so they shouldn't be `NULL`.

Below is the code I have used to get try and get the attributes values.

```
$user = craft()->userSession->getUser();
$user->getContent()->getAttributes()
```

Some values are filled out, like the custom field for postal code and phone number. However those category fields are all `NULL`.

Comment: Guess the additional parenthesis ")" inside getName is a typo? Anyways, if you use categories I think they're added to a relations table, and not to the user table. So you'd have to query for $categories->relatedTo($user)

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that should return categories related to a user:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Category);
$criteria->relatedTo = craft()->userSession->getUser();

return craft()->elements->findElements($criteria);
```